# Performance of str.strip for Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I thought the third option was supposed to be the fastest way to strip whitespaces? Can someone give me some general rules that I should be applying when working with large data sets? I normally use .astype(str) but clearly that is not worthwhile for columns which I know are objects already.

```
%%timeit
fcr['id'] = fcr['id'].astype(str).map(str.strip)
10 loops, best of 3: 47.8 ms per loop

%%timeit
fcr['id'] = fcr['id'].map(str.strip)
10 loops, best of 3: 25.2 ms per loop

%%timeit
fcr['id'] = fcr['id'].str.strip(' ')
10 loops, best of 3: 55.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: it maybe worth asking on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues) why this is the case as this is not what I'd expect

Comment: It'd be best to do a bit more profiling first to see what's causing the relative slowdown. In general your last two won't be equivalent since the pandas `.str` methods all 1.) take regexes or strings, 2.) handle NaNs without blowing up. Maybe see what the overhead of those looks like.

Comment: @TomAugspurger I did tests on a simple 30k row df: `df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['asds','as asd','asdsa   asdasdas']})
df = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)` and observed the same thing as the OP

Comment: @TomAugspurger timings: `In [8]:

%timeit df['id'].astype(str).map(str.strip)
%timeit df['id'].map(str.strip)
%timeit df['id'].str.strip()
10 loops, best of 3: 21 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 11.4 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 25.4 ms per loop`

Comment: And this is, as @TomAugspurger says, to be expected (that `map(str.strip)` is faster), as `str.strip()` does the same as `map(str.strip)` and more (checking for NaNs), so it will always be slower.

Comment: I guess the rule of thumb here is if you know that your data is simple and non-null then calling `.map(str.strip)` will be faster, otherwise for `NaN` handling and regex patterns then use the `pd.Series.str.strip`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's first look at the difference between `.map(str.strip)` and `.str.strip()` (second and third case).
Therefore, you need to understand what `str.strip()` does under the hood: it actually does some `map(str.strip)`, but using a custom `map` function that will handle missing values.
So given that `.str.strip()` **does more** than `.map(str.strip)`, it is to be expected that this method will always be slower (and as you have shown, in your case 2x slower).

Using the `.str.strip()` method has it advantages in the automatic NaN handling (or handling of other non-string values). Suppose the 'id' column contains a NaN value:

```
In [4]: df['id'].map(str.strip)
...
TypeError: descriptor 'strip' requires a 'str' object but received a 'float'

In [5]: df['id'].str.strip()
Out[5]:
0                   NaN
1                as asd
2        asdsa asdasdas
              ...
29997              asds
29998            as asd
29999    asdsa asdasdas
Name: id, dtype: object
```

As @EdChum points out, you can indeed use `map(str.strip)` *if* you are sure you don't have any NaN values if this performance difference is important.

---

Coming back to the other difference of `fcr['id'].astype(str).map(str.strip)`. If you already know that the values inside the series are strings, doing the `astype(str)` call is of course superfluous. And it is this call that explains the difference:

```
In [74]: %timeit df['id'].astype(str).map(str.strip)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.5 ms per loop

In [75]: %timeit df['id'].astype(str)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.25 ms per loop

In [76]: %timeit df['id'].map(str.strip)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.18 ms per loop
```

Note that in the case you have non-string values (NaN, numeric values, ...), using `.str.strip()` and `.astype(str).map(str)` will *not* yield the same result:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series(['  a', 10])

In [12]: s.astype(str).map(str.strip)
Out[12]:
0     a
1    10
dtype: object

In [13]: s.str.strip()
Out[13]:
0      a
1    NaN
dtype: object
```

As you can see, `.str.strip()` will return non-string values as NaN, instead of converting them to strings.